# Excel, create a generic space delmited string

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column of data in excel containing a number.

What I need is a formula that can add the word NA ( repeated with a space) for whatever the number value is, for example:

```
A1       A2  
3        NA NA NA  
1        NA  
8        NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Use the formula : `=REPT("NA ",A1)`

Answer (score 1):

Use the formula

```
=TRIM(REPT("NA ",A1))
```

to have spaces in between but not have a space in the end.